# How to end a switch case

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a class with random questions however the switch statement does not end and the questions keep going in a loop. How do I prevent this from happening and to display another page once all 4 questions randomly have been completed?

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Ans1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Ans2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Ans3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Ans4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Result: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton!
var correctAns = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Hide()
    Random()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func Random(){
    var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 4
    RandomNumber += 1

    switch (RandomNumber) {
    case 1:
        Question.text = "Where does minal lives?"
        Ans1.setTitle("dubai", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans2.setTitle("london", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans3.setTitle("india", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans4.setTitle("japan", for: UIControlState.normal)
        correctAns = "2"
        break
    case 2:
        Question.text = "What is my name?"
        Ans1.setTitle("Sunil", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans2.setTitle("Harish", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans3.setTitle("Rohit", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans4.setTitle("Minal", for: UIControlState.normal)
        correctAns = "4"
        break
    case 3:
        Question.text = "How old are you?"
        Ans1.setTitle("22", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans2.setTitle("32", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans3.setTitle("21", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans4.setTitle("28", for: UIControlState.normal)
        correctAns = "1"
        break
    case 4:
        Question.text = "What are you studying?"
        Ans1.setTitle("Computer Science", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans2.setTitle("Java", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans3.setTitle("Bio", for: UIControlState.normal)
        Ans4.setTitle("Business", for: UIControlState.normal)
        correctAns = "3"

        break

    default:
        Result.text = "Finished"
        break


    }

}

func Hide(){
    Result.isHidden = true
    Next.isHidden = true
}

func Unhide(){
    Result.isHidden = false
    Next.isHidden = false
}




@IBAction func Ans1Action(_ sender: Any) {
    Unhide()
    if (correctAns == "1"){
        Result.text = "Correct!"
    }
    else{
        Result.text = "Try Again"
    }
}


@IBAction func Ans2Action(_ sender: Any) {
    Unhide()
    if (correctAns == "2"){
        Result.text = "Correct!"
    }
    else{
        Result.text = "Try Again"
    }
}


@IBAction func Ans3Action(_ sender: Any) {
    Unhide()
    if (correctAns == "3"){
        Result.text = "Correct!"
    }
    else{
        Result.text = "Try Again"
    }
}


@IBAction func Ans4Action(_ sender: Any) {
    Unhide()
    if (correctAns == "4"){
        Result.text = "Correct!"
    }
    else{
        Result.text = "Try Again"
    }
}

@IBAction func NextAction(_ sender: Any) {
    Random()
    Hide()
}
```

}

Comment: Plaese have a look at [How to create a **minimal**, working and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not related, but in Swift there is no need for `break` statements and parentheses around `switch` and `if` conditions. And please consider the Swift naming convention.

Comment: it sounds like you simply want to display each of your (four) questions in a different order each time, yes?

Comment: not enough code shown.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I want a random order but once the questions hit 4 I want the quiz to end and display a label saying finished

Comment: Unrelated but the last thing you should be doing is hardcoding question and answer text into your code.

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess on several levels: (function names should start with a lower case letter; You should use an array of question structures rather than hard-coded cases that build the UI; You need to have some way of disabling the buttons if the user has answered all the questions...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a counter of the number of questions already asked. The `switch (RandomNumber)` will always enter one of the `case` statements, because `RandomNumber` is always in the range `1...4`.

So, what you need to do is add an instance variable

```
private var questionCounter = 0
```

and modify the `NextAction` function, something like this:

```
@IBAction func NextAction(_ sender: Any) {
    questionCounter += 1
    if questionCounter >= 4 {
        Result.text = "Finished"
        // or whatever...
    }
    else {
        Random()
        Hide()
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that by performing an `arc4random()` each time, the same question may appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of Int indexes from 1 to 4.

Extract an element from the array and display that item. When the array is empty, stop:

Something like this:

```
var questionIndexes = [1, 2, 3, 4]

if questionIndexes.count > 0 {
  let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(Uint32(questionIndexes.count)))
  let index =  questionIndexes.remove(at: index)
  askQuestionAtIndex(index)
}
```

(You'll have to adjust the code to fit in with your existing code, but that's the basic idea.)